# How to generate deterministic builds in c#. If we have the same code in different directories/machines

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, roslyn, deterministic

I am able to generate the deterministic build of a .net core console app by using
`<Deterministic>true</Deterministic>` this option in .csproj file.

I have used ILDASM to see the MVID. It is generating the same MVID if the source code is the same.

But, It is generating the different MVID, If the code is present in another directory/machine

Comment: Try asking on the Roslyn repo: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions

Comment: I think the path is considered an "input", so changing it is expected to give you different results. See: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/a053ed89aa84624605121e3e844d9faa5d504655/docs/compilers/Deterministic%20Inputs.md